# Hydration error using styled-components and React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I have next error.
I have two variants of theme in my app - dark & light.

Here is sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/trusting-mestorf-1rc2xv?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A7%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A7%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A11%7D%5D&file=%2Fpages%2Fboard%2F%5Bslug%5D.tsx

**ThemeContext.ts**

```
export const ThemeContext = createContext<{
  theme: AppThemeInterface,
  setTheme: Dispatch<SetStateAction<AppThemeInterface>>,
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  updateThemeKey: (newThemeKey: ThemeKeys) => void,
}>({
  theme: getTheme(ThemeKeys.DARK) // here is just object with props from interface,
  setTheme: () => null,
  updateThemeKey: () => null,
});
```

**AppThemeProvider.ts**
Here I receive theme_key from LocalStorage and get theme by that key and set it value to ThemeContext

```
export const AppThemeProvider = ({ children }: AppThemeProviderProps) => {
  const [currentThemeKey, setCurrentThemeKey] = useLocalStorage<ThemeKeys>('theme_key', ThemeKeys.DARK);
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<AppThemeInterface>(getTheme(currentThemeKey));

  const updateThemeKey = (value: ThemeKeys) => {
    setCurrentThemeKey(value);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={
      { theme, setTheme, updateThemeKey }
    }>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

useLocalStorageHook

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useLocalStorage = <T>(key: string, initialValue: T) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(() => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      return initialValue;
    }
    const lcItem = localStorage.getItem(key);
    const endVal = lcItem ? JSON.parse(lcItem) : initialValue;
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(endVal));
    return endVal;
  });

  const saveValue = (value: T): void => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  };

  const onChangeValue = (value: T): void => {
    saveValue(value);
    setValue(value);
  };

  return [value, onChangeValue] as const;
};
```

With such setup, when key in LocalStorage differ from **dark**, so in case in LocalStorage I have **light** i have next error

**

- Prop `className` did not match. Server:

**

That is because first it's rendered as dark theme, but then it rerenders with light theme.

I don't understand how to make it render properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

The state `value` will always be calculated on the server using the `initialValue`, however, when it's being calculated on the client it's using the key in localStorage (since `window` is defined on the client). For example, if the `initialValue` is "light" on the server, but may be "dark" in localStorage, you're going to get a hydration error because the `value` in state won't match.

#### Solution

Since localStorage is client-side only, you will need to calculate the theme value in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). In short, useEffect only runs on the client, therefore you'll always use the `initialValue` for both server and client, but on the client only, it'll be recalculated once the useEffect runs in the browser.

#### Demo

Here's a very simple [demo](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-localstorage-theme) that derives a theme based upon a value in localStorage.

Updated demo to include a [with-simple-cookie](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-localstorage-theme/tree/with-simple-cookie) example and a [with-redis](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/nextjs-localstorage-theme/tree/with-redis) example. This allows you to do server-side rendering, but comes with a drawback as mentioned below.

#### Drawbacks

Using a client-side stored value will result in a UI flash if the value is anything other than the `initialValue`. You could avoid this flash by moving the value to an outside resource that can be accessed server-side. For example, saving this value to a database that can be accessed by using one of the Next lifecycle methods: [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) or [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props). But this brings up another obstacle: **You will need to request this theme on every page load/transition** (and be opted-out of automatic static optimization). Regardless of whether a value is retrieved from the client or server, you're going to run into hurdles when it's used to dynamically set a global value.

#### Recommendations

I don't know what you're building this application for -- a business or personal growth -- so weigh the following recommendations according to your needs:

1. If having a customizable theme is more important than the app being SEO (indexed by a search engine), I'd recommend switching to the [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) or use a client-side only framework. On a related note, if the app is mostly behind an authentication layer -- you must sign in to view it -- then a client-side only framework would be more suitable. You could simply attach the theme as a property to the user model. When they log in to their account then their saved theme is applied to the app.
2. If the application needs to be SEO and it is not behind an authentication layer (or most of its routes are public), then I'd recommend not worrying about the UI flashing (eg. switching from light to dark). It's not ideal, but it'll only happen on an initial page load. Client-side transitions using `next/link` shouldn't be a problem provided the theme is defined within the `_app` page.
3. If the UI flashing on an initial page load results in a lower conversion and/or lower usage, then I'd recommend using a cookie-based approach. The downside to this approach is that it results in more requests, which could mean more costs. The trade off is that the UI wouldn't flash on an initial page load nor on client-side transitions. However, this also opts you out of [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization), which means all pages could load slower because the HTML isn't statically generated.

Comment: I've fixed it with useMountedHook(), you can check my codesanbox, please

Comment: I don't know how ideal that solving is, but it works

Comment: The reason your `useMountedHook` is working is because you're rendering the entire app on the client only. This means the app will not be SEO (search engine optimized) -- when a page is initially loaded, it's rendered on the server and then hydrated on the client. Right now, you're not rendering anything on the server and so nothing is hydrated on the client (this defeats the purpose of using Next.js). If this is going to be your approach, I'd recommend simply using the [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/), which is a client-side only template.

Comment: In short, if a bot were to crawl your app to index it for a search engine, it would index an empty `<div id=“__next”></div>` element because that’s what is being returned by the server for every page.

Comment: Here's a visualization of the server-side generated HTML using the above example as is: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/dhm43NF.png) and using your `useMountedHook` hook: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Fmrv9kf.png).

Comment: Okay, first of all, thanx for you patience and efforts which you did for me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I already see that it seems to be the wrong implementation of theming, what are you thoughts about it?

Comment: I've left a recommendations list in the answer above. Which approach you should take will depend on what is most important for the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ThemeContext = createContext<{
  theme: AppThemeInterface,
  setTheme: Dispatch<SetStateAction<AppThemeInterface>>,
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  updateThemeKey: (newThemeKey: ThemeKeys) => void,
}>({
  theme: getTheme(ThemeKeys.DARK) // here is just object with props from interface,
  setTheme: () => null,
  updateThemeKey: () => null,
});
```

Comment: it's just the same?